# Magento 2 Bulk Actions not Starting

Tags: cron, magento2.3.2, bulk-products-update

After trying to update attributes for 4 products in Magento 2.3.2 the Bulk Actions log shows that the update tasks have not started.

My Magento cron jobs appear to be running ok, why are bulk action tasks not starting?

[image]

**UPDATE**

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.3 I still had this problem. I had been using www-data as the file owner for my development system which I know is a bad practice. After resetting permissions as per Magento documentation and ensuring cron job was running as correct file owner the bulk actions run correctly.

**UPDATE Magento 2.4.x**

This problem has appeared again in Magento 2.4

See the following issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29797

Comment: Have you find the solution for this? I am also facing this

Comment: After a few days I noticed the bulk action tasks had ran. I need to test this some more as I do not know why the bulk actions failed to start, but then were executed some days later.

Comment: No, obviously there is a problem and we need to find out how to troubleshoot bulk action tasks.

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: upgrade to 2.3.3 ensure cron jobs are configured as per Magento docs.

Comment: Is there no solution for 2.3.2 version? please reply

Comment: I didn’t find a solution for 2.3.2.

Comment: Can you answer this one? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301545/bulk-product-attribute-update-fails-in-the-magento-2-back-end

Comment: My bulk update is not even starting.

Comment: @paj are you able to solve this? We are also getting this issue

Comment: Which version of Magento are you having the problem with, I fixed it with the info posted here and bulk tasks are working for me in 2.3.X and 2.4.1

Comment: @paj Magento 2.3.5 version

Comment: Still not working in 2.4.2 Enterprise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a bug to me.

I fixed it by modifying this function in vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations/Model/BulkManagement.php

Bad of me but hey, maybe it's a PR :)

```
private function publishOperations(array $operations)
 {
        $operationsByTopics = [];
        foreach ($operations as $operation) {
+            $this->entityManager->save($operation);
            $operationsByTopics[$operation->getTopicName()][] = $operation;
        }
        foreach ($operationsByTopics as $topicName => $operations) {
            $this->publisher->publish($topicName, $operations);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Well spotted! I expect it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Created a ticket https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23958

Comment: I have updated above code but not working.

Comment: I have updated my question I think file owner permissions / cron owner could be contributing to this issue.

Comment: I applied those code but it is not working. Any other solution for 2.3.2

Comment: @RajeshNagappan are you able to solve this?

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam did you solved ?

Answer (score 4):

**Magento 2.4**

This issue is solved here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/29814/files

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29797#issuecomment-698561956

If the old message is still shown then you can delete it from the `magento_bulk` and `magento_bulk_acknowledged` tables.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29797#issuecomment-700537460

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I manually started the queue with `php bin/magento queue:consumer:start product_action_attribute.update`, now all the tasks in the queue where running successfully.

But it looks like this is a bug and you shouldnt have to run this manually.

Answer (score 1):

The magento cron in your web server is disabled.
Set Magento cron by command line

```
crontab -e 

*/1 * * * * php -c {php.ini_path} {magento_path}/bin/magento cron:run
*/1 * * * * php -c {php.ini_path} {magento_path}/update/cron.php
*/1 * * * * php -c {php.ini_path} {magento_path}/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Or simply way is

```
php bin/magento cron:install [--force]
```

Comment: My cron jobs are running fine - just the bulk action tasks are not executing in a timely manner.

Comment: launch this command 'bin/magento cron:run'

Comment: after running bin/magento cron:run the bulk action task still has not ran - detail log shows it is pending in queue.

Comment: php version server??

Comment: should the cron jobs be ran as the file system owner?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is your idea, You can check again:

1. Check again connect magento 2 to rabiitmq(`php bin/magento queue:consumer:start`)
2. Check again process queue:consumer:start is starting(`ps aux | grep "queue:consumer:start"`)
3. Test Rest API with specifying API
4. Copy data to test bulk API with same data, same routers

Comment: If you have attributes that won't update that say they are queued, you can run: `php bin/magento queue:consumer:start product_action_attribute.update`

Comment: can u answer this question? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301545/bulk-product-attribute-update-fails-in-the-magento-2-back-end

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Magento 2.4.2. But was fixed after changed the db-schema.xml as describes in this post [How to Fix Magneto 2 Bulk Actions Not Starting](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-bulk-actions-not-starting/#For_Magento_24x_and_above)