# Remove Queued Bulk Actions

Tags: magento2.3.2, bulk-actions

I'm using 2.3.2 and having the issue outlined in this post:
[Magento 2 Bulk Actions not Starting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281723/magento-2-bulk-actions-not-starting)

And now I'm needing to remove the "Not Started" actions from the queue (as listed in the Bulk Actions Log). How would I accomplish this safely?

(edit: I did implement the fix from the linked thread, and it seemed to be successful, but seemed to be blocked by other bulk actions in the queue that haven't started)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the records you want to remove via the database directly in the magento_bulk table.

If you want to delete records of bulk operations that have already be execute you'd do the same with the magento_acknowledged_bulk table.

Comment: can u answer this question? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301545/bulk-product-attribute-update-fails-in-the-magento-2-back-end

Comment: Hello there, Thanks for the answer, So our client recently faced bulk operation notification not being able to clear till so many days, so they let us know for the resolve and we truncated the magento_bulk  & magento_acknowledged_bulk tables but yet the client can see old messages notifications for his admin user alone, all other users are good, can you suggest possible solution or right direction that we need to look into?