# Bulk Action Finished with Failure in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, bulk-products-update, bulk-actions

When uploading the attributes for multiple products it fails each time. Kindly help me to solve this problem. My Magento version is 2.3.2

Bulk action is not even starting.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 Bulk Actions not Starting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281723/magento-2-bulk-actions-not-starting)

Comment: Now the problem is fixed.

Comment: How did you fix the issue? can you share?